# Select specific element before other element

Tags: css

I have following HTML structure:

```
<div>
  <h2>Candy jelly-o jelly beans gummies lollipop</h2>
  <p>
    Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet. Sugar plum liquorice dragée oat cake cupcake.
  </p>
  <p>
    Candy tiramisu bonbon toffee. Croissant pudding ice cream soufflé pastry toffee  chocolate bar. Tiramisu wypas tootsie roll icing fruitcake oat cake icing soufflé tiramisu. 
  </p>
  <h2>Dessert pie cake</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>liquorice</li>
    <li>powder</li>
    <li>dessert</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Chupa chups sweet dragée</h2>
  <p>
    Chocolate cake biscuit pie jelly-o chocolate bar. Marshmallow topping sugar plum apple pie brownie cotton candy dragée lemon drops. Soufflé cake toffee.
  </p>
</div>
```

I would like to choose only that `h2` which is directly before `ul`. How can I do this? In my content there are many more `uls` and many more `h2s` so the solution should be universal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as I know, CSS doesn't offer any [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) which will target **before** a selector. Could you select it as an `h2` which is directly after a `p` (`p + h2`)?

```
h2 {
    color: #1a1a1a;
}

p + h2 {
    color: #0cc;
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZEYJ/)

As you can see, this is probably the best selector you can use if you're relying on CSS, although you could easily just add a class to each `h2` that is before a `ul`. That would avoid the case where you have a paragraph section before another `h2` and paragraph section.

You could do this using jQuery:

```
.highlight {
    color: #0cc;
}

$('ul').prev('h2').addClass('highlight')
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2DDA/)

This selects every `ul`, then selects the `h2` that is before it, before finally adding the `.highlight` class to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew about jQuery solution, but I was wondering whether it can be done in pure CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to select first anchor before my delete link , and I can't make `a` link inside andother `a` link , like this  `<a href="file.exe">file.exe</a>  <a href="" class="dlt">✖</a>`  the only solution workes are with JQuery ,

Answer (score 35):

To select **h2** elements that are directly before **ul** element

```
h2:has(+ul) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Please Note: It will not work on some browsers like Firefox, check [browser support here](https://caniuse.com/?search=has()).

Comment: thanks ! should be selected as best answer.

Comment:  this works great in all browsers that support the `:has()` tag. ignore the answers below that require js

Comment: This has seletor is great! Here's another example. This sets margin-bottom:0 on any element placed before any other element that has an attribute data-visible="false".
*:has(+*[data-visible="false"]) {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
*[data-visible="false"] {
 display:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

with this you can style just the first h2 element

```
h2:first-child { color:red; }
```

for browser support read here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17

Answer (score 0):

The rule h2~ul will not select h2 but ul. So you will not be able to apply any style to h2.

[CSS element1~element2](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp)

I have the same problem with panel location. I have a  element that is followed by a . And in this case I would like to reduce the height or the min-height (depends on the panels are fixed or not) of the main panel by style application.

In case of fixed footer, because I can declare the element before the main in my html file (it will be relocated by top/left properties) I can use the ~ selector like this: footer ~ main. But in case of non fixed footer, the only way I found is to add a class at document.ready() call.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this

```
div h2::nth-child(2) {

}
```

Comment: older  browser does not support this.. speciale <ie8 | read here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38

Comment: In my content there are much more `h2s` and much more `uls` so solution should be more universal.

Answer (score -6):

You can use the general sibling selector `~`.

In your case, you can use `h2~ul` that will apply to the h2 before `ul` inside the same parent.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wont. It will apply to all `h2` _after_ `ul` inside the same parent.

Comment: `h2 ~ ul` targets any UL with an H2 as a previous sibling. This example does not target an H2 element whatsoever.