# Floated box alignment issue

Tags: css

I'm building a responsive layout that has boxes in a grid at a certain screen size.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is add some top margin to box 3 to push it down to produce the desired effect:

[image]

- I don't want to apply a class to box 3
- I can't increase the width of the heading across because it resides in the box 4 container
- I wish I could target "the element before" with CSS but that [doesn't seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225364/select-specific-element-before-other-element)
- The boxes are currently floated, and I can't use `inline-block` due to responsive spacing issues

Comment: If these are floated boxes, why don't you try to add another <div> between 1 & 3

Comment: You could simply add annother heading tag above box number 3 and place a non-breaking space in it i.e. &nbsp;

Comment: @Prasanna an empty `<div>` the height of the heading? That would increase complexity of the responsive design and muddy the markup (although granted, not too bad).
@BillyMoat that would seriously muddy the markup, with an empty heading element. Also as the responsive design changes this would remain. They're all on one row on larger screens.

Comment: Simply adding `clear: both` to the heading element may do the trick.

Comment: The heading element is inside the box.

Comment: There is no CSS solution to this problem since you can't use `inline-block` and there is no baseline align for block elements. But, you can do this pretty easily using jQuery. (or plain old JS but it's harder)

Comment: I understand I can solve this with jQuery's `.prev()` but I'm looking for a CSS solution. Doesn't seem like it should be too difficult to achieve!

Comment: Actually, in "CSS4" (in quotes because [there will never be one](http://www.xanthir.com/b4Ko0)) you would be able to because there are/will be parent and previous sibling selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using pure CSS with the restrictions that you have. However, you can do it using jQuery:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/DKkLh/

jQuery:

```
$("section").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children("h1").length > 0) {
        $(this).prev().css("margin-top", ($(this).children("h1").height() + 5));
        // +5 for the margin on sections
    }
});​
```

Comment: I understand I can solve this with jQuery's .prev() but I'm looking for a CSS solution. Doesn't seem like it should be too difficult to achieve!

Comment: There isn't a baseline align for block elements, but if your `h1` was outside of the box or if you could use `inline-block` then it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put heading and div no4 in the same div/section and you will get the desired effect. Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx6mg/). 
Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: The heading is already in the box 4 container, as explained in question.Your fiddle seems to show the same problem on the other side. Second image is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: There you go... http://jsfiddle.net/Yx6mg/3/ Use display:inline-block instead of float.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I can't use `inline-block` for other responsive spacing issues ([info](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)).