# Target element right before other element

Tags: html, css

During my research for this, I stumble upon **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225364/select-specific-element-before-other-element)**, but since it is 2 years old, Im wondering if there's a recent way of targeting an element that is right before another.

For example:

```
<span> Element Before Div </span>
<div id="thediv"> Target Span From Here Using #thediv </div>
```

Is there any **CSS** that can accomplish this? 
I'm aware of the usage of **jQuery, I rather not use it** if this is possible with plain CSS.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Example to clarify usage.

```
  <ul>
     <li>
        <span>SubTitle Span</span>
        <div class="subdiv">Some content after SubTitle</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>Item Description</span>
        <div>Item Content</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>Item Description</span>
        <div>Item Content</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>SubTitle Span</span>
        <div class="subdiv">Some content after SubTitle</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>Item Description</span>
        <div>Item Content</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>Item Description</span>
        <div>Item Content</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>SubTitle Span</span>
        <div class="subdiv">Some content after SubTitle</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <span>Item Description</span>
        <div>Item Content</div>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Is this a real question ? Can you show us through a fiddle or codepen , why you would need this. There might be other _semantic_ ways to accomplish this.

Comment: It is a 'real question' for this reason. If i have a - ul - with 4 items, in the 3rd li I have a span that goes before a element with a class, lets say... <div class="thediv">Content</div><span>content</span> the only way to target that SPECIFIC span (assuming i have spans in all li items) is either give it a class or call it by: ul li nth-child(#position) span. When if the span was after, as stated in the answer below I just have to call it with a + or simply target it directly by #thediv span.

Comment: fine, but do you have a clear html structure to show what you mean and how why this would happen, naturally i would target the li. I just do not understand your situation. there is a parent selector maybe coming on CSS level 4 !<

Comment: My curiosity on this came up when I was building a <ul> that had the previous described situation and there was 3 specific <li> items that would act like sub-titles for a specific group. (Like groups in select boxes) And since I had a div right after the span that had a common class all across the 3 if there as a way t target a span that came right before that specific div would save me some time. I could simply say - .divclass (target previous) span - and I would have all my span in that position with the same style. I'll edit the question with this example.

Answer (score 1):

**No this is not possible using CSS alone**

if your HTML had been structured like below then yes CSS can be used

```
<div id="thediv"> Target Span From Here Using #thediv </div>
<span> Element Before Div </span>
```

for e.g to change the color of the span using the div, you would write as

```
#thediv + span {
color:blue;
}
```

this is called [adjacent sibling selecto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)r.

There is no way in CSS to target a previous element ,but a following element can be targeted like shown above.

Comment: This is stated in the post I referred. This I knew, what I was looking was a certain on the "Not Possible". Thank you.

Comment: @HélioC: This actually is going to change once CSS4 comes around, but that's still a ways off.

Comment: @Chuck: No, [it won't](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles), unless browsers decide to implement the 'Complete,' rather than 'Fast,' selector profiles.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed actually,  no way to select that `span`.

Level 4 propose this :

```
    !span li > div.subdiv {/* would style span if 
                              inside li that has a  
                              div.subdiv  
                              as direct child */}
```

so we could do as well: `!span li > div.subdiv:hover {}`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#subject (maybe i missunderstands subtilities of english) `<edit>` **actually i missed this : http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles** `</edit>`

Today,*(Apr. 14)* there is no way to directly style that `span` via CSS ,

but CSS can offer some *turn around* to hide it or change background color for instance.

like this silly test :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kxwtB/  over the div and believe that `span` receive some CSS styling.

Actually i was curious too of what kind of rules you wanted to see modified for the span .

Comment: I'm curious: have you actually read the spec/draft for Selectors Level 4? Because the spec explicitly states that the subject-indicator isn't available in the 'Fast profile' (as used in browsers), ref: [Fast vs Complete Selector profiles](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles).

Comment: thanks to point this to me, it makes sens. spec are a pain to read, and english is not my mother language, i pick it up working long ago as a chef in US Md., so i 'm missing lots of it :)