# hide an element on hover css that is not a direct child

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

There is a gap in my css knowledge here. I am trying to hide an element when another element is hovered on using styled-components.

```
const InnerBox = styled.div`
   background: green;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
`

const BoxTwo = styled.div`
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   background: red;
`

const Box = styled.div`
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   background: pink;
   // This works as InnerBox is in Box
   &:hover ${InnerBox} {
     display: none; 
   }
   // This doesn't work as BoxTwo is not in Box
   &:hover ${BoxTwo} {
     display: none; 
   }
`
```

My jsx looks like this:

```
<BoxTwo />
<Box>
    <InnerBox />
</Box>
<BoxTwo />
```

Does anyone know how to target the two BoxTwo from the hover on Box?

It looks like it is not [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033851/target-element-right-before-other-element). I can target the one after, but not the one before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: `Box:hover ~ BoxTwo .InnerBox`

Comment: You may want to add a tag for the framework you're using, because that isn't standard CSS nor JavaScript.

Comment: Are you hovering on the InnerBox or the Box? One is possible other is not with just CSS

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have updated tags. I mentioned it in the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `+` selector:

```css
#innerBox {
   background: green;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#boxTwo {
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   background: red;
}

#box {
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   background: pink;
}

#box:hover #innerBox,
#box:hover + #boxTwo {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="innerBox"></div>
</div>
<div id="boxTwo"></div>
```

In your case it will be:

```
&:hover + ${BoxTwo} {
  display: none; 
}
```

The `+` selector will only work when the element (`BoxTwo`) is placed immediately after the parent selector (`Box`).

Comment: ok, cool, this works. How about if it is placed before the element?I need to update the question slightly

Comment: @peterflanagan nope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector CSS does not go backwards.

Comment: @peterflanagan I am afraid you can't do that with CSS only.

Comment: god dang css :-D