# Getting the html element before another on hover

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to get the element next to an element that I hover over. So if I have:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="thing1"></div>
  <input type="text" class="thing2" />
</div>
```

When you hover over `.thing2` I want `thing1` to get a border applied to it. Is this possible? Here is what I have so far but it isn't working...

```
.thing1:hover ~ .thing2 {
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not opposed to using Javascript,  would recommend using [JQuery](https://jquery.com) to accomplish this.

Like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thing2').hover(function() {
    $('.thing1').css('border', '1px solid red');
    $('.thing2').mouseleave(function() {
      $('.thing1').css('border', 'none');
    })
  });
});
```

edit:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fbdjh5q/)

I also added code to remove the border when the mouse leaves. You can remove the following line if you do not want this behavior.

`$('.thing2').mouseleave(function() {
   $('.thing1').css('border', 'none');
})`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to reverse the order of `.thing1` and `.thing2` to get your desired result. And use positioning CSS to compensate the layout difference. Only then you'll be able to use the `.thing2:hover + .thing1` selector.

This is by means of a Pure-CSS solution without any JavaScript performance overhead.

Comment: I thought using the `~` operator was for getting the element that precedes?

Comment: CSS only reads forward, you can't select a parent element, nor a previous element. `~` is for anywhere after, and `+` is immediately after. [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

Comment: So if i reverse the order how can I use css to get them back in the order I need them? `thing1` has to be before `thing2`

Comment: You can use a number of things, [Flexbox + Order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order), [Floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), and [Absolute/Relative positions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) are some ways. Keep in mind that you may also have to adjust the `z-index` property if there is any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this link will help you**[Select specific element before other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225364/select-specific-element-before-other-element)

Css doesn't offer a selector which will target before a selector.

**What is the solution**
You can use jQuery, jQuery provides simple and beautiful methods for selecting.

**Common css selectors**
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

If jquery is an option you can set a class on thing1 when you hover thing2 by using:

```
$('.thing2').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).closest('.thing1').addClass('customBorderClass');
});
$('.thing2').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).closest('.thing1').removeClass('customBorderClass');
});
```

Then apply your css in the customBorderClass that gets added/removed on hover:

```
.customBorderClass {
    border-style: solid;
}
```