# Targeting all <li> element except one in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have this menu constructed with `<ul>` element

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item mobile-item">
    <a>Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The menu would look look something like this

Item 1 / Item 2 / Item 3

with the last element hidden with the class `.mobile-item`

On mobile the menu turns into an accordion then only the `.mobile-item` shows up

My problem now is the outcome is:

Item 1 / Item 2 / Item 3 /

The last class `item` has border on its right

How would I target the last `item` class without the `.mobile-item` in its class list

Comment: `ul > li:not(:last-child)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `:nth-last-child(2)` works in this case where you seem to want the second-to-last child:

```css
li.item:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item mobile-item">
    <a>Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this, BUT another thing I want to add is the menu consists of this multiple `<ul>` which consists of different counts of `<li>` and some might not have the `mobile-item` class for example a  ul with only `li.item`

Comment: @Joshua how does this solution depend on the `mobile-item` class? What wouldn't work with only `li.item`?

Comment: @Jere the `item` class `mobile-item` only gets shown on mobile size. the Solution rob presented affects those `ul` with only 2 `li` child

Comment: '_the Solution rob presented affects those ul with only 2 li child_'   That is not correct. Please see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-last-child)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this problem. I got inspiration for this answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10225449/16200422). With the following solution you could target the item before the item with the `.mobile-item` class. This selects the `.mobile-item` then the previous
`li` and adds the class `.highlight`.

```js
$('.mobile-item').prev('li').addClass('highlight')
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item mobile-item">
    <a>Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```